# Page shows up in web analytics - /_layouts/inplview.aspx?

Tags: 2010, web-analytics

What is the page /_layouts/inplview.aspx?

I am reviewing our web analytics on 2010 and notice that /_layouts/inplview.aspx tends to be at or new the top of the 'Top pages' rankings.  It seems to be related to some views in libraries.

I am looking for a better explanation of what it is and/or possibly a way to remove it from the stats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen that page called on Grouped list views to handle the AJAX callbacks. It's most likely being called for each expanded section on each grouped list view.

If your site makes use of these grouped views a lot then I'd be unsurprised that it ranked so highly.

What are you using for your web analytics?

Comment: I was digging around the OOTB analytics at the CA level and the Site Collection level.  We are looking at rolling out expanded permissions/access for departments to their Site Collections.  I want to make sure I understand and can explain why certain pages are in the stats.

Comment: I used Fiddler to watch the calls as I opened a library that used grouped views and saw the inplview.aspx calls as I expanded a grouping to see the individual docs.  Thanks Stuart.

Comment: @Jason: No worries. I'm afraid I haven't used the native analytics, so I can't help you with filtering out certain pages; although it sounds like it'd warrant it's own question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The /_layouts/accessdenied.aspx page tends to be one of the top pages.
I did look into the Sharepoint Reporting Database and found the function fn_WA_GetTopPages

Adding a condition to this function did filter out the /_layouts/accessdenied.aspx page.

But still we did not go with this solution as I dont think it is wise to modify the Sharepoint Database Functions..